# How to add class to two elements on checkbox click and preventing repeating url strings?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Background**

I have two tabbed containers (*grid and list view*) that have multiple elements(*info boxes*) with checkbox inputs within them, when one of these check box is checked, The background colour of the info box changes. The code also adds the id of the info box to the url stating which info boxes are selected.

**Example**

So the url with id number of 01 on would look like this: `www.example.com01=on`

**The problem:**

The grid and list views are displaying the same data just in different ways. So if 1 is selected on grid view and 1 is selected on list view the address looks like: `www.example.com01=on&01=on`

**Question:**

How can I fix it so that if a checkbox is selected then it changes the background colour of the info box in both grid and list views and if the same id is selected its doesn't repeat the number the url as in the problem example above?

**Example html structure:**

```
<div class="all">

<div class='vac_holder'>
<div class='child_vac'>
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd like" name="<?php echo $row['vac_id']; ?>">
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

**JS: adding checkbox id to the url string and adding class to the selected element**

```
var checkboxes = $('.all input[type="checkbox"]');
checkboxes.change(function() {
  var ser = '?' + checkboxes.serialize() + location.hash;
  history.pushState(null, null, ser);
});

$.each(location.search.replace('?', '').split('&'), function(i, seg) {
  $('[name=' + seg.split('=')[0] + ']').attr('checked', 'checked').parents('.vac_holder').first().addClass('pincard-checked'); 
});
```

**JS: checking all checkboxes with the same name**

```
$('.all input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    // If checked
    if (this.checked) $(":checkbox[name=" + this.name + "]").attr('checked', 'checked');
    else $(":checkbox[name=" + this.name + "]").attr('checked', false); // find other checkboxes with same value and uncheck them
})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/1289/)

Any help is much appreciated and sorry if my explanation confusing.

Comment: The Fiddle has been updated

Comment: what about tracking checkboxes using variables and create a function to update the presentation of the checkboxes with the onchange event?

Comment: @DavidNguyen That's pretty much what I have done. But the presentation change doesn't seem to be working and keeps repeating the id numbers in the url.

Comment: and if an info box is check in one view, it's not checked in the other view.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you are using pushstate here. and your $.each only runs once, it won't update checkboxes in the other tab until after a refresh.

Comment: oh, in the other tab? yes, that's the issue i'm getting.

Comment: your fiddle will never work until you replace the php code in the html with something else.

Comment: just been updated now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/1290/ I haven't investigated why my change fixed it, but all i did was simplify the logic in the change event.

Comment: That doesn't add the class to the info boxes tho.

Answer (score 0):

## Link and serialization

About your problem to link the checkbox in both `Grid`and `List`.

Let's assume you have `checkbox`like that.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd like" name="data1">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd like" name="data2">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd like" name="data...">
```

I use `dataX` to remplace you php `echo $row['vac_id'];`

`dataX`must be the same for a checkbox in `Grid`and `List` to create the link

### Javascript

Read comments for explanation

```js
checkboxes.change(function(e) {

  //Get the checkbox state
  var isChecked;
  $(this).attr("checked") ? isChecked = true : isChecked = false;

  //Get the 2 checkbox with in the list and the grid
  var selectedData = $('input[name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"]');

  //Set the 2 checkbox in the same state   
  selectedData = selectedData.prop('checked', isChecked);

  //Get the 2 selectedData checkbox parent
  var selectedDataParent = selectedData.closest('.vac_holder');
 
  //Add or remove class for style
  if (isChecked == true) {
    selectedDataParent.addClass("pincard-checked");
  } else {
    selectedDataParent.removeClass("pincard-checked");
  }
  
  
  //Use juste one of the 2 set of check boc for serialisation
  var checkboxesForSerialization = $('.grid input[type="checkbox"]');
  var ser = '?' + checkboxesForSerialisation.serialize() ;
  console.log(ser);

});
```

### Full code on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fu39Lwad/1/)

ps: This is the basic solution. Depending of your need, a solution more "MVC like" could be more suitable.

Comment: Wow! Great answer! Thank you very much! I see your using idData, can I use this like so: idData="<?php echo $row['vac_id']; ?>"

Comment: Oups, just forgot to save jsfiddle -Juste update the link in my answer.  idData is no longer use

Comment: lol :) I do that all the time haha. I'm getting an error now, says "checkboxesForSerialisation is not defined"

Comment: Update it again with  ^_^   checkboxesForSerialisation  ->   checkboxesForSerialiZation

Comment: :'( doesn't seem to be working for me on either auto selecting the same id or serializing.

Comment: My JS Fiddle don't work ?     If you speak about your project, could you check the output of `echo $row['vac_id'];`

Comment: Do you have a link where we can see the issue ?

Comment: I know why it's not working. It's coz of the version of jQuery, I'm using 2.2.1 I changed it in the jsfiddle and it stopped working.